# What are necessary & sufficient conditions for exponential family representation to have complete statistic $T(X)$?

Tags: inference, exponential-family, complete-statistics

My textbook gives the following theorem for exponential families:

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from an exponential family with pmf/pdf of the form $$f(x|\theta) = h(x) c(\theta) \exp (w(\theta)t(x))$$ Then the statistic $T(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n t(X_i)$ is complete.

But I'm unsure how to interpret this. It does not mention whether the family is curved, full rank, or of minimal dimension. And I feel like these conditions will certainly affect whether the statistic $T(X)$ is complete or not.

Am I right, and that extra conditions are not explicitly stated? Or is simply being an exponential family enough to imply completeness of $T(X)$?

Comment: The full rank condition is sufficient if not necessary. In the curved family $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ for example, the minimal sufficient statistic based on a sample of $n(>1)$ observations is not complete.

Comment: What is this textbook?